# Displacement of virtual image problem

Tags: geometry

An object is within a glass sphere of radius $R$ with a refractive index of $1.5$. I'm trying  to calculate the displacement of the virtual object relative to the actual when viewed from the side, such that the refracted ray emanating from the object becomes horizontal. I would like to know $S$ (the image shift) as a function of $d$, the distance of the object from the center of the sphere.

[image]

So far I've tried starting with Snell's law, $\sin\alpha = 1.5\sin\beta$, and manipulated it to get: $$\frac{\sqrt{R^{2}}-x^{2}}{R}=1.5\frac{x \cdot d}{R\sqrt{R^{2}-2d\sqrt{R^{2}-x^{2}+d^{2}}}}$$ where and $x$ is the distance from origin so $(S+d)^{2}+x^{2}=R^{2}$

The problem is it's too messy to rearrange to make $S$ the subject, but I'm guessing there's a better way.